# Getting SqlAlchemy joined query result as an array (or sthg similar)

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using many tables related with left outer joins in my queries,
I wonder if there is any way of getting easily the query result as a basic array, the type one can expect in phpmyadmin for example (I don't mean the layout).

Given 3 tables, all tables being mapped, I presently only get the result of the first table as an object, from which I have to test row after row if there is any results for table2, and so on for table 3 :

```
list_res_table1 = DBSession.query(table1).outerjoin(table2).outerjoin(table3).all()  
for res_table1 in list_res_table1:  
    if res_table1.relationship_to_table2:
        list_res_table2 = res_table1.relationship_to_table2
        for res_table2 in list_res_table2:  
            if res_table2.relationship_to_table3:
                etc.
```

It would be great to get a list of objects directly accessible like :

```
((table1, table2, None)    #=> no result for table3  
(table1, None, None)      #=> no result for table2  
(table1, table2, table3))  #=> results for all tables
```

Answer (score 2):

you can (and certainly should) query like this directly:

```
list_res_table1 = DBSession.query(table1, table2, table3).outerjoin(table2).outerjoin(table3).all()
```

the joining will look at the leftmost table first.  if you need more specificity, you can add in select_from() as well as explicit ON clauses:

```
list_res_table1 = DBSession.query(table1, table2, table3).\
                      select_from(table1).\
                      outerjoin(table2, table2.c.id==table1.c.t2id).\
                      outerjoin(table3, table2.c.t3id==table3.c.id).all()
```